# How i get the values in select option using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching acno from table when i select a party name in option.I have so far tired i get the acno from the table but it is not place in the option box.

My controller code:

```
 public function get_states2()
    {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT TAcNo FROM tipup_payment LEFT OUTER JOIN parmaster on parmaster.pcode =  tipup_payment.TName WHERE PName='$name' ")->result_array();
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

My View page code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group form-group-xs">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    Party Name:
<select class="form-control countries"  name="City">

<option></option>
<?php foreach ($PName as $row ): ?> 
<option value="<?php echo trim($row['PName']); ?>"><?php echo trim($row['PName']); ?></option><?php endforeach ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-xs">

<div class="col-lg-9">
    AcNo:
<select multiple="multiple" style="height: 85px;"  id="Name" class="form-control states">   
<option value=""></option>
</select> 
<?php echo form_error('Area', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="item">
<input type="checkbox" name="item">With Details</center></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Script Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

$('.countries').change(function(){
    var name = $('.countries').val();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Tieup/get_states2",
            data:{name:name}, 
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                    /*get response as json */
                    alert(data);
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var no = result.TAcNo;

                    $("#Name").val(no);

                    /*ends */

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my view page when i select a party name it should display the acno in acno option box( it down the party name).
[image]

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: the value is not set in the acno box but i get the value from the table

Comment: can u give the response u get

Comment: i get value in alert box [{"TAcNo":"341"}] but it is not set in the acno box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a class or id to ur dropdown
ur html

```
<select class="product">

</select>
```

ur jquery code 
loop through all ur value and set it in ur option value one by one and at the end inject all ur html to ur select option using `.html()`

```
var value =  [{"TAcNo":"341"}]
var options =  '<option value="">Select</option>';


$(value).each((index, item) => { //loop through your elements
  console.log(item)
  options += '<option value="'+item.TAcNo+'">'+item.TAcNo+'</option>';
});

$('.product').html(options);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it is not set value in the option

Comment: it not shows an error but in alert box shows an acno

Comment: did u set the class/ id in ur select ?
and where did u set this code inside success right ?
and what did u get when u `console.log(item)` ?

Comment: the number is not refresh it again

Comment: when i select another name the first acno is set and it is not change to another no

Comment: by the way why u did this `jQuery.parseJSON` it is deprecated already 
u just do this 
 var result = JSON.parse(data);
then console.log(result)
it should output `[{"TAcNo":"341"}]`

Comment: if the one party has 2 acno it will display the acno or not?

Comment: it will show both acno . as we run the loop it will loop through all ur data and set it to ur select. but if you want to show only one u have to put the condition there

Comment: u can cutomly set the value like 
var value =  [{"TAcNo":"341"},{"TAcNo":"3412"}]
and check u will find two dropdown value

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

**you need to trigger change like this to update select value**

$("#Name").val(no).change();